# Reevaluating styles returned from a function in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm making an app in Angular 6 and I have the following html:

```
<div #timeline class="p-timeline">
    <div class="p-marker" *ngFor="let exp of experiences; let i=index"
        [ngStyle]="getMarkerStyle(exp, i)">
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following typescript:

```
export class TimelineComponent {

constructor() { }

@ViewChild('timeline')
public timeline: ElementRef;

public getMarkerStyle(exp: ExperienceModel, i: number): any {
  if (!this.timeline || !this.timeline.nativeElement) {
    return {};
  }
  const element = this.timeline.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
  const height = element.clientHeight;
  return {
    top: ((height / (this.experiences.length - 1)) * i) + 'px'
  };
}
```

My question is: how do I 'rerun' the getMarkerStyle function when `this.timeline.nativeElement` becomes available? In order to set the top value?

I'm used to Vue.js which kinda has this functionality built-in.

New to Angular so open to advice on how to redesign the existing code.

Thanks!

Comment: where is timeline in your template?

Comment: @Mamta i've updated the original question to include the correct template